# Google not indexing the blogger-hosted blog after adding custom domain

Tags: google-search, godaddy, blogger

I had a blogger-hosted blog (.blogspot) , it was in the first search results at Google when looking up about a specific keyword.  9 months ago, I transfered the blog to a .com domain from GoDaddy.

When I did that, the blog posts were completely removed from Google. My website is not showing up at all when looking for the same keyword.  The new domain has a page rank 4/10 added my new domain to Google Webmaster tools.  I tried to change some meta tags, but nothing worked, my new domain is not showing up for anybody in Google except when searching the website name.

What could the problem be?

Comment: It looks like a redirection or configuration issue. Do you have more details? Is your new URL pointing correctly at your blog? I went through the same operation and it took a bit of time to recover my ranking. Google Webmaster Tools can provide you insights too...

Comment: @JVerstry Thank you, i have finally found the reason, i bought some paid backlinks in the past few months, and since then my Google rating was falling.. after the backlinks were removed, everything is back to work.